# Extract the points that generate the vectors x and y in the video

Tags: computer-vision, motion-detection, matlab-cvst, opticalflow

This code is an example of the Computer Vision System Toolbox, which generates the motion vectors of the optical flow. Curious as to extract from each video frame the array [x, y] with the coordinate points that make these vectors.

```
videoReader=vision.VideoFileReader('videoname','ImageColorSpace','Intensity',...
'VideoOutputDataType','uint8');

converter = vision.ImageDataTypeConverter;
opticalFlow = vision.OpticalFlow('ReferenceFrameDelay', 1);
opticalFlow.OutputValue = 'Horizontal and vertical components in complex form';
shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter('Shape', 'Lines', 'BorderColor',...
'Custom','CustomBorderColor', 255);
VideoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Name','Motion Vector');

videoInfo    = info(videoReader);
videoPlayer  = vision.VideoPlayer('Position',...
[100 100 videoInfo.VideoSize(1:2)+30]);

while ~isDone(videoReader)
frame = step(videoReader);
im = step(converter, frame);
of = step(opticalFlow, im);
lines = videooptflowlines(of, 20);
if ~isempty(lines)
   out = step(shapeInserter, im, lines);
    step(videoPlayer, out);
end
end

release(videoPlayer);
release(videoReader);
```

So googled the lines videooptflowlines = function (f, 20); generates the coordinate points of the lines of optical flow. I tried to put 'lines' in the command window waiting for me to return the array with this data, but apparently was not the expected array. As against this matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The motion vectors are  stored in `of`, which is a 2-D array of complex numbers. The real part contains the x-coordinates and the imaginary part contains the y-coordinates.